# Creating an array of JSON objects from another array of JSON objects

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I have a JSON array like this:

```
[{Company:"", FirstName:"John", SecondName:"Smith", ID:"2345"},
{Company:"SomeComp", FirstName:"", SecondName:"Kane", ID:"4363"},
{Company:"Random", FirstName:"Tom", SecondName:"", ID:"6454"}]
```

I want to parse this and create a new array of objects which only have non-blank attributes without IDs, i.e:

```
[{FirstName:"John", SecondName:"Smith"},
{Company:"SomeComp", SecondName:"Kane"},
{Company:"Random", FirstName:"Tom"}]
```

What is the best way of doing this in Javascript?

Comment: Just loop over the data? `for` or `map()`/`filter()` does not really matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

> The map() method creates a new array with the results of calling a
>   provided function on every element in this array.

```js
var companies = [{Company:"", FirstName:"John", SecondName:"Smith", ID:"2345"},
{Company:"SomeComp", FirstName:"", SecondName:"Kane", ID:"4363"},
{Company:"Random", FirstName:"Tom", SecondName:"", ID:"6454"}];
   
// This returns a new array
var newArray = companies.map(function(item) {
     var obj = {};
     for(var prop in item) {
          if (item[prop] !== "" && prop !== "id" ) {
              obj[prop] = item[prop];
          };
     }
     return obj;
});
 
console.log(newArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it

```
var input = JSON.parse("<YOUR JSON HERE>");
var output = [];
input.forEach(function(item) {
     delete item.ID;
     for (var prop in item) {
         if (item.hasOwnProperty(prop) && item[prop] === "") {
              item[prop] = undefined;
         }             
     }
output.push(item);
});
```

Comment: Any reason you didn't use map?

Comment: To be honest, no. It crossed my mind but my brain erroneously told me it was `map` was an underscore / lodash feature.

Comment: Two suggestions: This modifies the objects in the original array which I'm not sure is desirable, though it's not clear from the question but sounds like it since the OP wants a new array.   If modifying the original object is OK, consider using `delete item[prop]` so the the unwanted property doesn't show up in a `for` loop.

Comment: @JuanMendes I agree :)